# How to use Itext7's CreateTiff method in parallel foreach loop?

Tags: c#, itext7, parallel.foreach

I wrote some code to convert tiff files into pdf files via Itext7. But when i  start it, it has deadlocks on method `Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateTiff`. If replace Parallel.Foreach with foreach all works correct. What I do wrong?

```cs
void Run(List<string> tiffsPaths)
{
   Parallel.ForEach(tiffsPaths, ConvertTiffToPdf)
}

void ConvertTiffToPdf(string tiffPath)
{
   var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tiffPath);
   var pdfPath = Path.Combine(this.outputPicPath, fileName + ".pdf");

   var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfPath);
   var document = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
   var workDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(SourceFile) ?? string.Empty;
   var pageNum = 1;

   var tiffImage = Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateTiff(new Uri(tiffPath), true, pageNum, true);
   var tiffPageSize = new Geom.Rectangle(tiffImage.GetWidth(), 
   tiffImage.GetHeight());
   var newPage = document.AddNewPage(new Geom.PageSize(tiffPageSize));
   var canvas = new PdfCanvas(newPage);
   canvas.AddImage(tiffImage, tiffPageSize, false);

   document.Close();
   pdfWriter.Close();
}
```

**UPD**
Found where deadlock is happend inside *IText7* source code in method `public IRandomAccessSource CreateSource(Uri url)` of class `itext.io.source.RandomAccessSourceFactory`. There this part of code:

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
Stream isp = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: are you sure that `Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateTiff` is thread-safe?

Comment: No, I'm not sure that this method is thread-safe. I thought that static methods should designed thread-safe

Comment: Looks like that one isn't

Comment: Yep, looks like something wrong with WebRequest inside IText7 source code

Answer (score 1):

Replaced `var tiffImage = Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateTiff(new Uri(tiffPath), true, pageNum, true);` with `var tiffImage = Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateTiff(File.ReadAllBytes(path), true, pageNum, true);` and all works fine